# How to change the font for an entire row in tabularray?

Tags: fonts, tabularray

Given a `tfm` file, I can use that font as in the MWE given below. I
also can change the font for any row using the standard commands/styles
like `\bfseries`, `\ttfamily`, `\scshape` etc.

I would like to change the font for some row to say `\andk`. Using
`\SetRow{font=\andk}` does not work. How can I set/change the font for a
row to a font of my choice?

```
\documentclass{article}
% 
\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

{\font\andk=andk-Bold-tlf-sc-t2b at 14pt\andk
Hello}
\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{
  width=0.9\textwidth,
  colspec  = {llr}
  }   
\toprule
  Month & Day & Number \\
\midrule
  Jan   & Wed & 10 \\
\SetRow{font=\bfseries\sffamily}
  Feb   & Mon &  0 \\
  Mar   & Sun & 20 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\font\andk=andk-Bold-tlf-sc-t2b
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec    = {Q[l,m]Q[l,m]Q[c,m]},
row{3}     = {cmd=\andk},
hline{1,Z} = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}   = {wd=.05em},
}
Month & Day & Number \\
Jan   & Wed & 10     \\
Feb   & Mon & 0      \\
Mar   & Sun & 20     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This may not be what you are looking for, but here is a solution that uses `fontspec`. In this example, I've changed the font of row 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
% 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Arial Nova}

\begin{document}

%{\font\andk=andk-Bold-tlf-sc-t2b at 14pt\andk
%Hello}
%\bigskip

\begin{booktabs}{
    width=0.9\textwidth
    ,colspec  = {llr}
    ,cell{3}{-}={font=\myfont}
}   
\toprule
  Month & Day & Number \\
\midrule
  Jan   & Wed & 10 \\
%\SetRow{font=\bfseries\sffamily}
  Feb   & Mon &  0 \\
  Mar   & Sun & 20 \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but as you noted it needs `fontspec`, which means  I have to use `lualatex` or `xelatex`. As I have to use `pdflatex`, I would like a solution which is compatible with that.

Comment: @mas Why you need compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: The font I use is not compatible with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.